# StatusBar tint and hidebaronswipe

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I just want to change the color of my statusBar to follow the color of my navigationController.

I've read some posts, and now I'm understand that I'm not able to change the statusBar color, basically, I need have a view behind and change the color of that view. Ok.

So my problem is:

I have a UITableView inside a ViewController and this ViewController is embed in a NavigationController.

In the NavigationController I set the flag `Hide Bars:On Swipe`

When I swipe the TableView my navigationBar disappear, but it also override my view that I set to a height of 20 to simulate the StatusBar.

I found this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319449/ios-hidesbarsonswipe-status-bar-background-color), and it is the exactly my problem, I've read on this post a logical solution, but OP don't answered if it worked or not, anyway, I think that I need to work correctly with the constraints, but this solution doesnt work for me on xcode7 swift 2.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post images here for better unterstand

Comment: Sorry, I don't thought necessary because I linked a Post that is exactly my problem, and It have all the Images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the perfectly solution on this post:

The solution marked as accepted is outdated.

[Autolayout: Add constraint to superview and not Top Layout Guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766210/autolayout-add-constraint-to-superview-and-not-top-layout-guide)